# Converting from decimal ascii to binary in visual studio macro assembler

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

I have been given a project that requires me to add two one or two digit numbers and return the result. I'm given most of the code, but I am supposed to fill in the part where we convert the decimal ascii values read in from the command prompt to their binary equivalent. The subroutine is as follows:

```
;input decimalbuffer, BufLength
;OutPut BinValue
RETURN_BIN_VALUE PROC NEAR C USES eax ebx ecx edx esi edi ebp,
decimalbuffer:ptr byte, Blength:ptr word, BinValue:ptr word
CALCULATE_BIN_VALUE:
```

if there are only 2 digits then
`BinaryValue = (D0 = 30h) + 0Ah * (D1 - 30h)`
where `D0` is the second element of the array decimalbuffer and `D1` is the first element

```
DONE:
    Ret
RETURN_BIN_VALUE ENP
```

My problem here is that I don't understand the macro assembler's syntax. How am I supposed to indicate that I want to access the first and second element? I've looked around all of my notes and on the internet and I haven't been able to find anything. I barely started using the micro assembler last week. Up until then I was using debug in DOSBox. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 'My problem here is that I don't understand the macro assembler's syntax' - unless you learn some of this, together with 386 architecture and adressing modes, you have no chance at all of completing your assignment.  'I've looked around all of my notes and on the internet and I haven't been able to find anything' - unreal statement - there are hundreds of sites devoted to 386+ assembler.  About 250ms of searching supplied Wiki 'x86 assembly language'.  Indexing characters with offsets and register indirect is easy on x86.  Why not try some stuff?